# How to add an event in FullCalendar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

In my FullCalendar, the time is displayed at the top, and there are several resource columns created. If I remove these resources, events are created, but if I add at least one resource, nothing happens. How to solve this problem?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>CodePen - FullCalendar Scheduler Clone events</title>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.9.0  /fullcalendar.min.css'>


<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar-scheduler/1.9.4/scheduler.min.css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">

</head>
<body>

<div id="calendar"></div>

 <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
 <script src='https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>
 <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js'></script>
 <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.9.0/fullcalendar.min.js'>  </script>
 <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar-scheduler/1.9.4/scheduler.min.js'></script>
<script  src="./script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>



$(function () {// document ready

$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
now: '2023-12-01',
editable: true, // enable draggable events
droppable: true, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar 
allDaySlot: false,
allDayDefault: false,
navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
selectable: true,
selectHelper: false, 
eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events 
aspectRatio: 1.8,
scrollTime: '00:00', // undo default 6am scrollTime
header: {
  left: 'today prev,next',
  center: 'title',
  right: 'timelineDay' }, //,timelineThreeDays,agendaWeek,month 
defaultView: 'timelineDay',
views: {
  timelineThreeDays: {
    type: 'timeline',
    duration: { days: 3 } } },`

resourceLabelText: 'Rooms',
resources: [
{ id: 'a', title: 'Auditorium A' },
{ id: 'b', title: 'Auditorium B', eventColor: 'green' },
{ id: 'c', title: 'Auditorium C', eventColor: 'orange' },
{ id: 'd', title: 'Auditorium D', children: [
  { id: 'd1', title: 'Room D1' },
  { id: 'd2', title: 'Room D2', eventColor: 'green'  },
  { id: 'd3', title: 'Room D3', eventColor: 'orange' },
  { id: 'd4', title: 'Room D4' },
] },
{ id: 'e', title: 'Auditorium E', eventColor: 'green' },
{ id: 'f', title: 'Auditorium F', eventColor: 'red' },
{ id: 'g', title: 'Auditorium G', eventColor: 'yellow'  },
{ id: 'h', title: 'Auditorium H', eventColor: 'orange'  },
{ id: 'i', title: 'Auditorium I', eventColor: 'green' },
{ id: 'j', title: 'Auditorium J', eventColor: 'red'  },
{ id: 'k', title: 'Auditorium K', eventColor: 'orange'  },
{ id: 'l', title: 'Auditorium L', eventColor: 'yellow'  },
{ id: 'm', title: 'Auditorium M', eventColor: 'orange'  },
{ id: 'n', title: 'Auditorium N', eventColor: 'green' },
{ id: 'o', title: 'Auditorium O', eventColor: 'red'  }, 
{ id: 'z', title: 'Auditorium Z', eventColor: 'green' }],

events: [
{ id: '1', resourceId: 'b', start: '2023-12-01T02:00:00', end: '2023-12-01T05:00:00', title: 'event 1' },
{ id: '2', resourceId: 'c', start: '2023-12-01T05:00:00', end: '2023-12-01T11:00:00', title: 'event 2' },
{ id: '3', resourceId: 'd', start: '2023-11-06', end: '2023-11-08', title: 'event 3' },
{ id: '4', resourceId: 'd1', start: '2023-11-06', end: '2023-11-08', title: 'event 10' },
{ id: '5', resourceId: 'e', start: '2023-12-01T03:00:00', end: '2023-12-01T08:00:00', title: 'event 3' },
{ id: '6', resourceId: 'k', start: '2023-12-01T03:00:00', end: '2023-12-01T08:00:00', title: 'event 4' },
{ id: '7', resourceId: 'i', start: '2023-12-01T03:00:00', end: '2023-12-01T08:00:00', title: 'event 5' },
{ id: '8', resourceId: 'f', start: '2023-12-01T05:30:00', end: '2023-12-01T15:30:00', title: 'event 6' },
{ id: '9', resourceId: 'l', start: '2023-12-01T03:30:00', end: '2023-12-01T05:30:00', title: 'event 7' },
{ id: '10', resourceId: 'm', start: '2023-12-01T01:30:00', end: '2023-12-01T07:30:00', title: 'event 8' },
{ id: '11', resourceId: 'n', start: '2023-12-01T00:30:00', end: '2023-12-01T08:30:00', title: 'event 9' }],

select: function(start, end) {
  var title = prompt("Event Content:");
  var eventData;
  if (title) {
    eventData = {
      title: title,
      start: start,
      end: end
    };
    $("#calendar").fullCalendar("renderEvent", eventData, true); // stick? = true
  }
  $("#calendar").fullCalendar("unselect");
},

eventClick: function(calEvent) {
  console.log(calEvent)
  // var title = prompt("Edit Event Content:", calEvent.title);
  calEvent.title = "111";
  calEvent.start = "2023-11-20T10:00:23Z";
  calEvent.end = "2023-11-20T12:00:23Z";
  $("#calendar").fullCalendar("updateEvent", calEvent);
}, 
  });
```

I need that when clicking on any part of the calendar, an event is created.

Comment: `eventData = {
      title: title,
      start: start,
      end: end
    }` doesn't include a resourceId. So if you're showing a view with resources, then there is nowhere for non-resource events to be displayed. Therefore, it won't show up. If you want to use resources, make sure you specify a resourceId when adding the event. As per the [documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/select-callback) the resource that was clicked on is supplied through the `select` callback.

Comment: P.S. I don't know why you're using such an old version of fullcalendar. Version 6 is the latest (you're using version 3) - it has more features, fewer bugs, and better performance. Unless you're maintaining some existing code, there should be no reason to use version 3